# How to change date format and time zone with DatePicker(moment.js) in React(Ant Design v4)?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

How to change date format and time zone with Ant Design DatePicker?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named timezones. Include [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
 moment(birthday).tz('America/Toronto').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

or use .utcOffset(). This function uses the real offset from UTC.

```
moment(birthday).utcOffset(60).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

[About format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)